# How do I connect to Google Cloud SQL using SSH

Tags: google-app-engine, ssh, google-cloud-sql

How do I connect to Google Cloud Platform, specifically Cloud SQL, using SSH? I’m using Tera Term and can’t seem to get in. Maybe I’m just using the wrong host, port, password or configuration settings. I’ve tried several combinations.

I can connect to my Google Cloud SQL instance using MySQL workbench, so I’m pretty sure I’ve configured the Cloud SQL Access Controls correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cloud SQL provides a managed MySQL endpoint and not a virtual machine in which you can SSH into.

Comment: Thanks, Razvan. Sometimes the questions hardest to answer while digging through support documentation are those that have the simple answer, "Not possible."